# Passing a value from a slider in one view controller to an int value in another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uislider

I am trying to pass a value from a slider in one view controller to a property of type int in another view controller. One changed, I don't want to change the view controller hence sugue is not an option. Could anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

The following header and main files are of the view controller which contains the slider. Information has to be passed from this view controller.

SliderViewController.h

```
#import "IntViewController.h"

@property (strong, nonatomic) IntViewController *intViewController;
- (IBAction)sliderValue:(UISlider *)sender;
```

SliderViewController.m

```
#import "SliderViewController.h"

@interface SliderViewController ()

@end

@implementation SliderViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.intViewController = [[IntViewController alloc] init];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"%i", self.nearbyViewController.kms);
}

- (IBAction)sliderValue:(UISlider *)sender {

    [self.intViewController setKms:(int) sender.value];
    NSLog(@"%i", self.intViewController.kms);
}
@end
```

Both the NSLogs are printing the desired value over here.

The following header and main files are of the view controller to which the information has to be passed.

IntViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic) int kms;
```

IntViewController.m

```
#import "IntViewController.h"

@interface IntViewController ()

@end

@implementation IntViewController
@synthesize kms;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSLog(@"%i", self.kms);
}
```

The NSLog keeps printing 0 here.

Comment: `[[IntViewController alloc] init]` creates a new object and, since you don't present it, the view is not going to appear.  What you probably want is a reference to an existing `IntViewController` object.  Alternatively, you could use some kind of data model that is updated by the slider and read by the other controller.

Comment: @PhillipMills I am using tab bars, IntViewController is at index 0 in tab bar while SliderViewController is at index 4. Could you tell me how can I get a reference of IntViewController from SliderViewController.

Comment: You could create a custom subclass of your tab bar controller and have it pass the `IntViewController` as a type of delegate to the `SliderViewController` in an `awakeFromNib` call...or wherever you know all the controllers are set up correctly.